# Parse MVC route custom file extension from RequestContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, path, requestcontext

I have set up two custom extensions to enable MVC in IIS6.

So the site can be accessed with a URL of either something like...

`mysite/mycontroller.europe/myaction`

or like...

`mysite/mycontroller.america/myaction`

What is the most robust way of finding the extension from the `RequestContext` instance?

So I would like to be able to write something like...

```
var location = reqContext.......GetExtenstion(); // location = "europe"
```

and obviously have that work even if the setup of the site/directories changes a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultWithExtension",
    "{controller}.{extension}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", extension = "america" }
);
```

and then:

```
var extension = RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("extension");
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can just define extension as a string parameter for all relevant actions for the controllers, in which case it will be directly available.
e.g.

```
public ActionResult myaction(string extension)
```

This does still need the mapRoute entry defined above.